# Is an en dash before 'which' proper punctuation?

Tags: punctuation, dashes

In this sentence

> In conclusion, the reading claims that minimum wage is harmful to the companies, which the lecturer contradicts by providing three points –which form a compelling argument, to illustrate his viewpoint.

Is it grammatical to use "–" before *which*? And if so, should I replace the comma at the end of the same clause with an em dash as well? Or should I only use commas to set off the clause?

Comment: Too many `which` and too many `points`... _In conclusion, the reading claims that minimum wage is harmful to the companies, contradicted by the lecturer in three points, which together form a compelling argument illustrating his view._

Comment: Looks like proof-reading. We're getting rather a lot of these.

Comment: @BarrieEngland you know, proof reading is good B-)

Comment: But proof-reading is off-topic on this site. This question would be more suitable at [ell.se]

Comment: If you put one dash (—) in that sentence, you need to put another in. That is, the phrase *"which form a compelling argument"* should be set off by two dashes or by two commas, but not by one of each. If you set it off by commas, the sentence becomes confusing because you have too many *which* clauses separated by commas. This is a good reason for either using dashes or rewriting the sentence.

Comment: @PeterShor thanks for your comment, so what do you think of the commennt that Mr. mplungjan made? do you think it would be better to use dash ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with grammar. This is about punctuation. Also, do note the difference between a [hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) an a [dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash). Using a hyphen as sentence punctuation, as you originally did, is plain wrong. Anywhere, in any sentence. Hyphens are for being used inside *words*.

Comment: Peter Shor is correct about the need for a pair of em-dashes, if you use them at all. In contrast to the em-dash, an en-dash has very narrow application—most notably to connect a span of numbers ("1988–1996") or a compound involving a multiple-word name and a second word ("Civil War–era"). Here's a simpler way to express the idea in the original sentence (no dashes of any kind required): "The reading claims that minimum wage is harmful to the companies, but the lecturer persuasively disputes that conclusion on three grounds."

Comment: Note that you normally use **em** dashes for this kind of break in a sentence, and **en** dashes to write things like ranges. However, some typographers dislike **em** dashes and replace them with an **en** dash surrounded by spaces. “Like—this” or “like – this.”

Answer (score 2):

If we set aside the structure of the sentence (which I think could be improved), you *can* put an em-dash there, but if you do, you should also replace the comma at the end of the clause, thusly:

> In conclusion, the reading claims that minimum wage is harmful to the companies, which the lecturer contradicts by providing three points—which form a compelling argument—to illustrate his viewpoint.

Putting em-dashes there makes it sound as though you are surprised that the three points form a compelling argument.

If you use commas instead, they should also match:

> In conclusion, the reading claims that minimum wage is harmful to the companies, which the lecturer contradicts by providing three points, which form a compelling argument, to illustrate his viewpoint.

In this instance, commas are appropriate because the clause is parenthetical. *However,* I don't think you really mean to have a parenthetical clause there, so you might try something like:

> In conclusion, the reading claims that minimum wage is harmful to the companies, which the lecturer contradicts by providing three points that form a compelling argument to illustrate his viewpoint.

Which would avoid the issue entirely.

Comment: so what is better : `In conclusion, the reading claims that minimum wage is harmful to the companies, which the lecturer contradicts by providing three points that form a compelling argument to illustrate his viewpoint.` OR `In conclusion, the reading claims that minimum wage is harmful to the companies, contradicted by the lecturer in three points, which together form a compelling argument illustrating his view` ? please help me i have a toeff tomorrow

Comment: Either is fine. It depends on whether "form a compelling argument to illustrate his viewpoint" is important or not.

Comment: yes it is very important